# Using find command to search for files in one directory which are not in the other, then move them

Tags: linux, bash, find, gnu

I would like to be able to use the GNU `find` command in BASH to find any exact filenames in somedir_v1 that do NOT match any filenames in somedir_v2, and then move those files from somedir_v1 into newdir_v1

The thing is, while I could just copy somedir_v2 over somedir_v1, and have newer versions of certain files, both of these directories have 40GB files. I also don't even know if access time (atime) will update when I move them, so I might not know what files were previously inside, what files were replaced and what wasn't replaced. Anyway, I'm not going to do it this way.

If there's a bash line I can use, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Just use the cp command with the --no-clobber option.  It will skip things that exist already and your time stamps will be up to date.

Comment: You may also want to learn about the `rsync` command.  It excels at this sort of thing.